# Relation between TDateTime::FormatString and SysUtils::FormatDateTime

Tags: datetime, string-formatting, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

When using the `TDateTime` method `FormatString` to get a string representation with millisecond-precision, I'm getting perfect results when using the `zzz`format specifier. But it is not documented for the  [TDateTime::FormatString Method](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TDateTime__FormatString.html), whereas it is for the [SysUtils.FormatDateTime Function](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FormatDateTime@string@TDateTime.html).

I tried to look up the implementation of the appropriate `TDateTime` method in the sources, since a duplicate implementation was much less likely than an outdated/out-of-sync documentation.

I found nothing so far. Is there indeed no relation between these both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [zzz] is not documented for the [TDateTime::FormatString](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TDateTime__FormatString.html) Method, whereas it is for the [SysUtils.FormatDateTime](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FormatDateTime@string@TDateTime.html) Function.

You are looking at old documentation on the old Embarcadero Documents website.  The latest `TDateTime::FormatString()` documentation is available on Embarcadero's newer DocWiki site:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime.FormatString

The `zzz` specifier was added to the documentation in XE5:

> zzz  Displays the milliseconds (000-999).

> I tried to look up the implementation of the appropriate TDateTime method in the sources, since a duplicate implementation was much less likely than an outdated/out-of-sync documentation.
>
> I found nothing so far. Is there indeed no relation between these both?

The C++ implementation source code for `TDateTime` is in the `$(BDS)\source\vcl\datetime.cpp` file.  `TDateTime::FormatString()` simply calls `SysUtils.FormatDateTime()` directly:

```
System::String __fastcall TDateTime::FormatString(const System::String& format) const
{
  return Sysutils::FormatDateTime(format, *this);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Exactly what I was looking for (by grepping falsely within `*pas|*.inc|*.int` files)